# Jquery: How to access object value using dynamic key

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to get the `object` value with dynamic key. I have data array with keys that is:

```
Array[15]
 0:Object
   applied:43
   institute: ACET
   selected:  12
   year: 2013
 1:Object
   applied: 50
   institute: PTU
   selected:  10
   year: 2015
 .......
```

now from this data i just want to get all `institute` names and i am using `jquery map` function get the data:

```
var newData = vm.chart_data.map(function(obj) { return obj.institute; });
        console.log(newData);
```

if i am giving `return obj.institute` manually its working fine, but when i have to get the multiple keys value or when i am using in loop then i can't get the value from that object array:

```
var values = ['institute','year'];
var newData = vm.chart_data.map(function(obj) { return obj.values[0]; });
        console.log(newData);
```

is there any way to get that values?